# Large Square Matrices in C

Tags: c

ive been trying to create a program which creates square or nxn matrices in C. However, when n goes past 16000, ive found out that it always results into a seg fault. How can I solve this? Here is a snippet of my code generating the matrices:

```
double **X = (double **)malloc(n * sizeof(double *));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
X[i] = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
if (X[i] == NULL) {
  printf("Memory allocation failed for row %d. Exiting.\n", i);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
}


double *y = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
if (y == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation failed. Exiting.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Initialize matrix X and vector y with random values
srand(time(NULL));
printf("\nMatrix X (%d x %d):\n", n, n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        X[i][j] = rand() % 3 + 1;  // Random integer between 1 and 10
        //printf("%.2f ", X[i][j]);
    }
    //printf("\n");
}

printf("\nVector y (%d x 1):\n", n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    y[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;  // Random integer between 1 and 10
    //printf("%.2f\n", y[i]);
}
```

Comment: When n = 16k, numbers in 16k by 16k matrix with double precision (8 bytes) makes more than 2 GB of memory. That might be the problem.

Comment: @ssd only noticed this now given but changing double to int made it work. occupying values ranging from 1-10 made the change negligible. Thank you!

Comment: Note that if it's an issue with a 2 GiB limit on allocated space, then I would expect the change from `double` to `int` (or `float`) to get you only up to about 23k x 23k.

Comment: @JohnBollinger running the code now, i noticed this issue to come up. what can i do to go past this?

Comment: If your system is limiting how much memory you can allocate, and you need more, then your should first look into whether there is a way (command-line option, configuration setting, *etc*.) to get your C implementation to allow that.  If you are running on a 32-bit system, however, then there probably isn't.

Comment: If you're already getting as much memory as the system can provide, and that's inadequate, and you can't move to a more powerful system, then you'll need to devise a way to work with only some of your data resident in memory at any given time, with the rest stored on disk (which will need to have large enough capacity itself).  That's tricky, but techniques for that kind of thing were well developed and widely used back when memory was a much more precious resource than it usually is today (60s, 70s, ...).

Comment: If you only need to store the values `[1, 10]`, you can try using `unsigned char` (a single byte), and avoid pointer overhead: https://godbolt.org/z/KThhz54P8 (~44k²).

Comment: @JohnBollinger im at a loss for now with regards to that tbh. Ill look into it when I can tho. Thanks!

Comment: @Oka this would work for now thankfully as I had to generate up until 40k. Thank you!

Comment: @Oka you can even pack 2 values into a single byte because that range is so small. But the OP likely is compiling in 32-bit mode which is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the numbers themselves, you may want to generate the numbers procedurally on-line, as needed. For example, this uses the [MurmurHash3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) 64-bit mixing function to map the coördinate, flattened into an integer, into a random-ish but deterministic matrix. Every run picks out one new seed from the time.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

/** <https://github.com/aappleby/smhasher> `src/MurmurHash3.cpp fmix64`. */
static uint64_t fmix(uint64_t k) {
    k ^= k >> 33;
    k *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccd;
    k ^= k >> 33;
    k *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53;
    k ^= k >> 33;
    return k;
}

static uint64_t seed, n;

static unsigned matrix(const uint64_t x, const uint64_t y)
    { return fmix(seed + y * n + x) % 10 + 1; }

static unsigned vector(const uint64_t i)
    { return fmix(seed + 0xff51afd7ed558ccd + i) % 10 + 1; }

int main(void) {
    // Initialize matrix X and vector y with one random seed and size.
    seed = (uint64_t)time(0);
    n = 5000000000;

    printf("\nMatrix X (%" PRIu64 " x %" PRIu64 "):\n", n, n);
    printf("%u %u %u %u...%u %u...\n", matrix(0, 0), matrix(1, 0),
        matrix(2, 0), matrix(3, 0), /*...*/ matrix(0, 1), matrix(1, 1));

    printf("\nVector y (%" PRIu64 " x 1):\n", n);
    printf("%u %u %u %u...%u %u\n", vector(0), vector(1),
        vector(2), vector(3), /*...*/ vector(n-2), vector(n-1));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Just be careful for `fmix(0) = 0`.

Edit: you don't actually need to choose `n` at all. You can use the diagonally distributed numbers (triangular numbers) in the quarter-plane to extend to infinity (or as far as 64-bits).

```
static unsigned matrix(const uint64_t x, const uint64_t y)
    { return fmix(seed + (x + y) * (x + y + 1) / 2 + y) % 10 + 1; }
```